# Fabric log format to display date and time

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko

I have set Fabric up to log all SSH/Paramiko-related output with a level of INFO or higher using:

```
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('ssh.transport').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

This results in a log looking like this:

```
[host1] Executing task 'task1'
[host1] Run: ls
...
```

Is it possible to change the formatter for the ssh.transport logger so that each line also has the date and time printed next to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [alecxe said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949464/901641), the format is hardcoded in Fabric 1.x (as of when I'm posting this, the only version available.) There was [a rejected pull request](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/pull/1140) that could have remedied this.

So instead we need a work around. This is a rather hacky solution that I wrote, but it relies on undocumented portions of Fabric, which means it may break in future versions.

```
from fabric.io import OutputLooper
from datetime  import datetime

def newFlush(self, text):
    stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S - ")
    print(stamp + text)

OutputLooper._flush = newFlush
```

From this point forward, any output from your remote machine will have timestamps.

For example, without this code the output from `sudo('echo "test"')` would be:

```
[InteractSL-DT1.usma.ibm.com] sudo: echo "test"
[InteractSL-DT1.usma.ibm.com] out: test
[InteractSL-DT1.usma.ibm.com] out:

'test'
```

But after adding that, you'll now get this:

```
[InteractSL-DT1.usma.ibm.com] sudo: echo "test"
Fri Jan 02 12:54:49 - [InteractSL-DT1.usma.ibm.com] out:
Fri Jan 02 12:54:49 - test

Fri Jan 02 12:54:49 - [InteractSL-DT1.usma.ibm.com] out:
Fri Jan 02 12:54:49 -

'test'
```

You can play around with this basic idea to clean it up. The `sudo` line at the start of the output comes from `fabric.operations._run_command`, around line 900. I'm not sure of any simple way you could modify it.

Comment: is it possible to print datetime once during "Executing task" line ? instead of printing every line of out ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible now. The format is hardcoded: see [source](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/operations.py#L903).

FYI, there is a [proposal](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/163) that is asking for exactly what you are.

---

You can set logging format with an `asctime` inside, but it won't affect fabric output, only paramiko ones:

```
import logging
FORMAT = "%(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)
```

example output:

```
[host] Executing task 'restart'
[host] sudo: ls
2013-09-23 02:36:54,800 paramiko.transport Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_5.3)
2013-09-23 02:36:55,728 paramiko.transport Authentication (password) successful!
2013-09-23 02:36:55,889 paramiko.transport Secsh channel 1 opened.
...
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, have been unable to find a way to do this aside from replacing `_flush()`. I generally find it's a risky practice to replace a private method in any class, let alone a third party. Here's a solution that decorates the Fabric `_flush()` method and also uses the native Python `time.asctime` method to format the timestamp.

```
def time_decorator(msg):
    """
    Decorates `msg` with current timestamp
    Args:
        msg(str): The log message from fabric
    Returns: 
        str: Original message prepended with current date time
    """
    if "\n" not in msg and msg.strip():
        return "[%s] %s" % (time.asctime(), msg)

    return msg


# Compose original method inside of decorator
_original_flush = OutputLooper._flush
OutputLooper._flush = lambda self, msg: {
    _original_flush(self, time_decorator(msg))
}


@task
def uptime():
    run('uptime')
```

Testing it out, your output should resemble something like:

```
> fab uptime -H 10.0.1.3,10.0.1.2
[10.0.1.3] Executing task 'uptime'
[10.0.1.3] run: uptime
[Thu Dec 15 19:34:35 2016] [10.0.1.3] out:  19:34:35 up 69 days,  4:22,  1 user,  load average: 0.05, 0.03, 0.05
[Thu Dec 15 19:34:35 2016] [10.0.1.3] out:

[10.0.1.2] Executing task 'uptime'
[10.0.1.2] run: uptime
[Thu Dec 15 19:34:35 2016] [10.0.1.2] out:  19:34:35 up 70 days,  1:12,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
[Thu Dec 15 19:34:35 2016] [10.0.1.2] out:


Done.
Disconnecting from ec2-user@10.0.1.3... done.
Disconnecting from ec2-user@10.0.1.2... done.
```